# Installing Kobo module on the system along with python 2.7.3

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have python 2.7.3 installed on my system an I am trying to install Kobo module. The path where the module is located is:

```
C:\Users\nelson.menezes\Desktop\new softwares\kobo-0.3.6
```

.I opened the command promt and set the above mentioned path. Then as specified I run the following command to install Kobo.

python setup.py install

But it gives me the following error

```
File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\util.py", line 204, in convert_path
raise ValueError, "path '%s' cannot be absolute" % pathname
ValueError: path '/usr/bin' cannot be absolute
```

I know that it an error generated due to Path problems. But I cannot figure out how to resolve it. It would be great if anyone could help in any possible way.

The full traceback is as follows:

```
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
running install_data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 91, in <module>
    scripts      = script_files,
  File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 575, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\command\install_data.py", line 58, in run
    dir = convert_path(f[0])
  File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\util.py", line 204, in convert_path
    raise ValueError, "path '%s' cannot be absolute" % pathname
ValueError: path '/usr/bin' cannot be absolute
```

Comment: Can you show us the **full** traceback?

Comment: @MartijnPieters i have added the tracebach.

Comment: This looks like the `setup.py` file is using absolute paths, and it may be that `kobo` cannot be installed on *Windows* machines. The project is, after all, a [Fedora project](https://fedorahosted.org/kobo/).